# ExtJS 4 MVC Best way to create linked combos

Tags: extjs, model-view-controller

I want to create linked combos, for example we have 3 combo: 2nd depends of 1st selection and 3rd depends of 2nd selection. All with remote store.

For now I use something like this:

```
onFirstComboSelect: function( t, recs ) {
    var _rec = recs[0];
    this.getSecondCombo().enable();
    var _secondComboStore = this.getSecondCombo().getStore();
    _secondComboStore.getProxy().extraParams.firstComboValue = _rec.get('id');
    _secondComboStore.load();
},
```

This is listener for select event and it is work well. For 3rd combo listener is similar. But, when I want to load this set of combos with a set of parameters some problems appear. I have to set a value for the first box (I do it with setValue() method), set extraParams for the second combo store, make an ajax request, wait for an answer and in callback run same actions for 3rd combo, etc. I'm not sure that is the best way.

Example:

```
    if( window.data ) {
        var _data = window.data,
            _self = this;

        if( _data.firstComboValue ) {
            // select first combo value
            this.getFirstCombo().setValue( _data.firstComboValue );

            // select second combo value
            var _secondCombo = _self.getSecondCombo(),
                _secondComboStore = _secondCombo.getStore();
            _secondCombo.enable();
            _secondComboStore.getProxy().extraParams.firstComboValue = _data.firstComboValue;
            _secondComboStore.load( {
                callback: function() {
                    if( _data.secondComboValue ) {
                        _secondCombo.setValue( _data.secondComboValue );

                        //select third combo value
                        var _thirdCombo = _self.getThirdCombo(),
                            _thirdComboStore = _thirdCombo.getStore();
                        _thirdCombo.enable();
                        _thirdComboStore.getProxy().extraParams = {
                            firstComboValue: _data.firstComboValue,
                            secondComboValue: _data.secondComboValue
                        };
                        _thirdComboStore.load( {
                            callback: function() {
                                if( _data.thirdComboValue ) {
                                    _thirdCombo.setValue( _data.thirdComboValue );
                                }
                            }
                        } );
                    }
                }
            } );
        }
    }
```

Also I have an idea: instead of using 3 different stores (with 3 different .php handlers on the server in my case) with same id / text model for 3 combos I can make a single store with firstId / firstText / secondId / secondText / thirdId / thirdText model and use it for all 3 combos. This way I will realod data for all combos on each select event, but for that I get an opportunity to easily install a set of data in the boxes without having to do a lot of nested callbacks. What do you thinks about it?

I apologize for any errors in spelling and description of my question, I will be happy to give more detailed explanations if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write three models or three handlers methods in your case. You  can define next combo box id in every combo box like given as below.

```
items:[
{
  xtype:'combo',
  id:'combo-1',
  nextComboId:'combo-2',
},
{
  xtype:'combo',
  id:'combo-2',
  nextComboId:'combo-3'
},
{
  xtype:'combo',
  id:'combo-3'
}]
```

now you can use once common method to handle select event of combo-1 and combp-2 and you can do same for as many combos as you want.

`onComboSelect: function( combo, recs ) {
    var nextCombo = combo.nextComboId;
    nextCombo.getStore().getProxy().extraParams.comboValue = _rec[0].get('id');
    nextCombo.getStore().load();
}`

Comment: Thats looks nice, but what if I need for 3rd combo set both values, from combo-1 and combo-2, to extraParams? Also, how is it can help me load this set of combos with set of parameters? I will update my question with example.